# according to apple my App crashes on ipv6 network on iPad but unable to find and resolved it

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

I have done the setting on my Macbook Pro given on below link:

**https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1**

**Screenshot of setting** 
 **http://prntscr.com/dmx0jw**

, now my mac has bacome hotspot for my all testing device , but how to confirm is it ipv6 or ipv4 network ,

but how to find that crash which apple had pointed.

Answer (score 0):

After you set up your mac for NAT64 Network according to the documentation that you linked, connect another device with your app installed to the wifi network. Then run the app and see if it crashes. If it crashes, you can check where the error is and see if it is at the same place in the crash log that Apple Review Team should have sent along with the app review rejection.